# Swift get value from api possible threading issue

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, google-places

I have a function that does an api request using google's places api. From the api response data I capture a value and try to set it to a variable. This function is called inside another function. I then try to access that variable but unfortunately the variable doesn't contain the value yet. This appears to be a threading issue but I don't know how to fix it.

update: 
I have updated the code based on the responses. Unfortunately I am still not able to access the variable with the value from the api request. I have rewrote the function that does the api request to use a completion handler. The mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapInfoWindowOfMarker marker: GMSMarker!) is a function from the google maps framework. Would I need to rewrite this as well to use take a completion handler ?

// variable

```
var website = ""
```

// code with api request

```
func getWebsite2(id: String, completion: (result: String) -> Void)  {

    var url = NSURL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=\(id)&key=AIzaSyAWV1BUFv_vcedYroVrY7DWYuIxcHaqrv0")

    self.dataTask = defaultSession.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
        data, respnse, error in
        let json : AnyObject
        do {
           json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
            var dictionArr = json["result"]
            self.website = dictionArr!!["website"] as! String
            print(self.website)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)

        }
    }
    self.dataTask?.resume()
}
```

// second function

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapInfoWindowOfMarker marker: GMSMarker!) {

    let storeMarker = marker as! PlaceMarker

        self.getWebsite2(storeMarker.id!) {
            (result: String) in

            print("inside did tap")
            print(self.website)
            // problem still here 
           // above two lines of code never run
    }

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toWebView", sender: nil)
}
```

// I initialize defaultSession and dataTask like this.

```
let defaultSession = NSURLSession(configuration:       NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
var dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask?
```

Comment: The network request is async, so the rest of the code is running before the network request has finished. You need to write your function `getWebsite2` to take in a completion block, in the same way that `defaultSession.dataTaskWithURL` allows you to pass in a completion block

Comment: Thanks to you and Oleg for the responses. I am currently following you and Oleg's suggestion and attempting to use completion handlers. I will post an update when I figure it out

Comment: It is not clear how `defaultSession` is initialised from your snipplet. Assuming it is a local reference to `NSURLSession.shared()`, the code will be run on a different thread and cause a data race. You need to wrap `self.website = ...` in a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){...}` closure.

Comment: I tried putting the getWebsite2 function call inside dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){...} and I tried putting just the print statements inside dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){...} within the function call. Unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: @user2378197 I edited the post to show how I initialize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not invoking the completion handler passed into the `getWebsite2` function.  This (pseudo)code shows how to take the string received from the server and pass it to the closure invoked in `didTapInfoWindowOfMarker`.

```
func getWebsite2(id: String, completion: (result: String) -> Void)  {

    self.dataTask = defaultSession.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
    data, response, error in

        // now on background thread
        let someStringFromNetwork = data[0]

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            completion(someStringFromNetwork)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly do not force unwrapping of the variables and always use `do{} catch{}` where it is required.

This small code block that show how you should handle `try` and `if let` conditions:

```
   do {
        let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
        if let dictionary = jsonObject["result"] as? [String: String] {
             self.website = dictionary["website"]
        } else {
             print("Parse error")
        }       
    } catch {
        print("JSON error: \(error)")
    }
```

Secondly `defaultSession.dataTaskWithURL` is asynchronous request that will set data only when he will finish.

In another worlds you try to print value when request is not finished.
For solving of youre problem you should use [Completion Handlers](https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/).